# How to post a twit using C# with username and password?

Tags: c#, api, twitter

I used `tweetsharp` API to post a twit using `access token` it is working fine. Now I need to implement with username and password to post the twit. Is it possible to post a twit using `username` and `password`?.

If yes which API is good option to twit using `user credentials`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: **[Twitter Libraries](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiO9d3QjtvdAhWCiaYKHSSHDDAQFjAAegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.twitter.com%2Fen%2Fdocs%2Fdeveloper-utilities%2Ftwitter-libraries.html&usg=AOvVaw0syKeFDWX1KKWb9aXVA_73)**.

Comment: There's only one API, isn't there? [POST /statuses/update](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update) There are some other twitter API endpoints that accept standard HTTP basic authentication, so you could try that for this too and see if it works? But OAuth is going to be a better bet really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter API requires that you use OAuth (an authenticated access token) to use the `statuses/update` endpoint. So, no, it is not possible to post a Tweet using just the username and password.